# Datasnap - prevent users from running another instance

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, datasnap

If one instance of Datasnap server is running, trying to open another one crashes this second instance. How can you prevent users from opening more than one instance of datasnap server?

On create of the server application :

```
Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TServerContainer1, ServerContainer1);
  Application.Run;
```

I tried putting LMDOneInstance on the Form1 but the server still keeps opening another instance (visible in the windows task manager). It does not crash the newly created instance but it just creates another process.

[image]

Comment: When you say "trying to open another one", do you mean "trying to launch another instance of the server"?  The reason I ask is that I am not clear why you would allow end users to launch the server in the first place ...

Comment: Create a global Mutex (SyncObjs.TMutex) to check if there is already an instance running on the computer

Comment: MartynA - It's not going to happen (I hope so) but just in case ...

Comment: @user763539.  The best way to avoid it is not to allow them execution access to the server.

Comment: @MartynA is right. Trying to stop users doing this just obfuscates your code. Tell them not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `JvAppInstance` on a data module, and it will handle the rest.

Comment: dont have jedi vcl components for delphi xe4

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. It should be posted as such to the original question.